# How to use navigation component in fragment Android

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I want to use Navigation component in my fragment.

My XML code like this

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    ...

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_nav_host_home"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/home_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_bar" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And Initializing navigation code like this.

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

   //...initialie view


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val navController = Navigation.findNavController(binding.fragmentNavHostHome)
        navController.setGraph(R.navigation.home_navigation)

        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity, navController, appBarConfiguration)

    
    }

}
```

And after I launched my app, I got an error message like this.

```
View androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView{... app:id/fragment_nav_host_home} does not have a NavController set
```

Also, findNavController() does not work.

How can I use navigation component in my fragment

Comment: you should provide activity's navHostFragment as the parameter to he .findNavCotroller

Comment: @ErenTüfekçi Does activity's navHostFragment mean FragmentContainerView in my activity XML?

Comment: I solved this problem by using childFragment manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Kotlin Answer**

Key point is that try to use *childFragmentManager* in ***onViewCreated()*** function.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

  // Define container.
  val loginDialogContainer = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container) as NavHostFragment

  // Set nav controller.
  val loginNavController: NavController = loginDialogContainer.navController
}
```

Comment: Did you try like this? --> "childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container) as NavHostFragment"